# Developing an Spring Boot application with Angular2 TypeScript in Idea: gradle processResources wathing mode wanted

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, spring-boot, npm

I am developing a Spring Boot application in IntelliJ Idea with Angular2 TypeScript UI with Gradle build system.
When I run my program from IntelliJ Idea. In the background I run a `npm run tsc:w`.

details from package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    ...
  },
```

As I change the typescript code, the new code isn't available from webapp, until I run a `gradle processResources` in command line.

I think the problem is that the Spring Boot app serves the file from the build direcory not from the resources library.

Are there a watching possibility in gradle processResources like in the typescript compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution:

`gradle processResources -t`

watches for changes and reprocess them if necessary.